WordPress Custom Block Not Rendering on the Front-end?
I've developed a custom WordPress block for displaying medical terms. The block functions perfectly in the editor page, allowing users to search for terms and displaying the results accordingly. However, when I view the page on the frontend where the block should be displayed, it doesn't appear.
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";
import { useSelect } from "@wordpress/data";
import { useState } from "@wordpress/element";
import { Button, TextControl } from "@wordpress/components";

const dummyData = [
    { id: 1, title: "Term 1", excerpt: "Description of Term 1" },
    { id: 2, title: "Term 2", excerpt: "Description of Term 2" },
    { id: 3, title: "Term 3", excerpt: "Description of Term 3" },
    // Add more dummy data as needed
];

registerBlockType("custom-blocks/medical-terms", {
    title: "Medical Terms",
    category: "widgets",
    edit: () => {
        const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
        // Use dummyData directly instead of fetching from WordPress
        const terms = dummyData.filter((term) =>
            term.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()),
        );

        return /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(TextControl, {
                label: "Search",
                value: search,
                onChange: setSearch,
            }),
            /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(Button, null, "All"),
                [...Array(26)].map((_, index) =>
                    /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                        Button,
                        {
                            key: index,
                            onClick: () => setSearch(String.fromCharCode(65 + index)),
                        },
                        String.fromCharCode(65 + index),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                "ul",
                null,
                terms.map((term) =>
                    /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                        "li",
                        {
                            key: term.id,
                        },
                        /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement("h3", null, term.title),
                        /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement("div", {
                            dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
                                __html: term.excerpt,
                            },
                        }),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    },
    save: () => null,
});




You haven't defined the output in your save function. That function is responsible for creating the HTML output that will be displayed on the frontend.
